# tmux doesn't inherit PATH variable when inside docker?

Tags: python, environment-variables, docker, tmux

I am trying to run `tmux` inside docker container. It runs but looses variables like `PATH`, for example inside container:

```
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# ls /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# which python
/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# echo $PATH
/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/java/bin:/opt/bitnami/spark/bin:/opt/bitnami/spark/sbin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then inside `tmux` inside container:

```
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# ls /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# which python
root@sparkmaster:/opt/bitnami/spark# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

i.e. some paths are absent, like path to Python, but not all paths.

Why and how to fix?